# How can I check if a value exists in a dictionary that is nested within a loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary, flask

I am trying to increment the quanitity value if the item name is already in the dictionary nested within a list, the method I was planning on using is by checking if itemname doesn't already exists in the dictionary then add to the list, else if it does exist in the dictionary then update thw quantity by one.

I'm not too sure how to check to see if the itemname is in the nested dictionary iv'e looked around but haven't found anything

```
@app.route("/AddToCart", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def addToCart():
    itemId = int(request.form.get("productId"))
    MenuItem = Menu.query.get(itemId)

    if MenuItem is None:
        return render_template("error.html", errorMessage="There has been an issue adding this item to your basket")

    sVars = session['cart']

    if(MenuItem.ItemName not in sVars):
        sVars.append({'Itemname': MenuItem.ItemName, 'Itemprice': float(MenuItem.ItemPrice), 'Qty': 0})
    else:
        sVars['Qty'] += 1

    session['cart'] = sVars

    allPrices = Money(amount=sum([x['Itemprice'] for x in sVars]), currency='GBP')

    return render_template("cart.html", cartSession=session['cart'],allPrices=allPrices)
```

Comment: if "myvalue" in mydic: returns a boolean value

Comment: can you give example of your nested dictionary so that we can help.

Comment: @JainilPatel dictionary is on line 9after sVars.append you should see the curly braces

Comment: got your problem....

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is work for me

```
def check_exist(my_dict, key):
    if key in my_dict.keys():
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this would be to replace this section of code:

```
    sVars = session['cart']

    if(MenuItem.ItemName not in sVars):
        sVars.append({'Itemname': MenuItem.ItemName, 'Itemprice': float(MenuItem.ItemPrice), 'Qty': 0})
    else:
        sVars['Qty'] += 1

    session['cart'] = sVars

    allPrices = Money(amount=sum([x['Itemprice'] for x in sVars]), currency='GBP')

    return render_template("cart.html", cartSession=session['cart'],allPrices=allPrices)
```

with:

```
    cart = session['cart']
    for item in cart:
        if item['Itemname'] == MenuItem.ItemName:
            item['Qty'] += 1
            break
    else:
        cart.append({
            'Itemname': MenuItem.ItemName,
            'Itemprice': float(MenuItem.ItemPrice),
            'Qty': 1
        })

    totalPrice = Money(
        amount=sum([item['Itemprice'] * item['Qty'] for item in cart]), 
        currency='GBP')

    return render_template("cart.html", cartSession=cart, allPrices=totalPrice)
```

Some notes: First, your original code tries to use `sVars` *both* as an array (with `.append()`) and as a dictionary (with `sVars['Qty']`). It has to be one or the other, of course. I am assuming that it is an array, but correct me if that assumption is wrong (and show an example of it).

Second, my suggested code uses a Python feature that many are unfamiliar with, an `else` block with a `for` loop. If you haven't see this before, it's designed for just this kind of use. The way it works is that if the loop is explicitly exited with a `break` statement, the `else` block is not executed.  If the loop runs to completion, then the `else` block *is* executed.

Finally, I assume that `allPrices` should be the total price of all items in the cart, so each item's price should be multiplied by its quantity.

Comment: Thanks this worked, however I changed the session['cart'] to sVar as for some reason the items get removed after I add a new item keeping sVar has solved this issue for me

Comment: Glad that helped. I made a couple of changes to the code in my answer after first posting it, not sure if you were looking at the original or revised code. In any case, if you would like to edit your question to add your working code, we could see what that issue was about. Please keep the original code as is, and add a new code section with your updated code.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have a list like this:

```
ls = [{"Itemname": "Test", "Itemprice": 1, "Qty": 0}, {"Itemname": "Test1", "Itemprice": 1, "Qty": 0}]
```

then you could have a function like this to update the items:

```
def updateItems(inpdic):
    for item in ls:
        if item["Itemname"] == inpdic["Itemname"]:
            item["Qty"] += 1
            return
    ls.append(inpdic)
```

you go over all the items in the list, if an item with the same name exists you increase the quantity and exit, otherwise you append it.

Answer (score 0):

```
sVars=[]


flag=0
indexgot=0

for i in sVars:
    if(i['Itemname']=='item1'):
        flag=1
        indexgot=i


if(not flag):
    sVars.append({'Itemname': "item1", 'Itemprice': float(50), 'Qty': 0})
else:
    sVars[sVars.index(indexgot)]['Qty'] += 1

print(sVars)
```

just an approach ... to solve your problem.